# is there a standard way of inserting additional html into directive template for one off cases?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4, angularjs-directive

I have a directive w/ a template that will work in 90% of scenarios. However there are some scenarios where I'll need additional fields be added to the template. Is there a way to extend or modify an existing html template so that adding additional fields is a possibility without rebuilding 90% of an existing template?

I know that you can compose a new directive w/ a base directive. However this only serves to add functionality and content around the base directive and doesn't allow for the ability, from what I know, to insert additional html into or around the base template in a way that allows for the additional html to be recognized in the context of the base html.

In my case I have 5 standard input fields. However in some cases I need to insert additional input fields, not before or after the base 5 but literally intersperse them between the base inputs. Using bootstrap, I can apply an order to the various input fields and theoretically i can take the the additional inputs into account and supply orders accordingly. However, bootstrap cannot recognize the inputs as being part of the same row-cols ordering logic if the base content is separated into a containing div separating its content from that of any directive which composes off of it.

It seems like angularjs's directives are specifically designed to group base directive content into a single and separate container object. This is the error if you try and use the directives replace functionality w/o having a single template container: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/error/$compile/tplrt

Is this simply a short coming of angularjs's abilities for composition or is there some other piece to this puzzle that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply do this on the front end with ... So that the input fields in question would only show up if your edge case is true. Save your condition variable in scope and based on that display/hide the fields. Unless I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: I mean, yes I can but I'm trying not to include one off logic in the standard directive. Otherwise a one off scenario might negatively affect a standard scenario. My idea is that the base directive is how the ideal scenario operates and that I'd compose a new directive / UI w/ it when I need to add fields to that base set.